# Can defeated Servants be summoned again?

Tags: fate-stay-night

Let's say Bob for some reason takes part in the 6th holy grail war. He then posseses the weird snake relic from Gilgamesh and attempts to summon him? Does this work? Or does it fail because Gilgamesh was defeated in the last war?

Comment: Excluding weird cases like Saber, the answer should be yes - a hero, once defeated, returns to the Throne of Heroes, from where it should be possible to summon them again. I don't know of any instances where this has happened, though.